# Spring factory bean returning more than one object

Tags: spring

I would like to read an external configuration file that is not in a standard spring xml format and create FooBean(s) based on that file.

The Spring BeanFactory interface enables the creation of only one object, and I would like to return zero or more objects, depending on the external configuration file.

Should I implement FactoryBean where FooBeansHolder is a dummy class holding FooBean(s)?
Or should I implement FactoryBean,ApplicationContextAware and inject the beans to the BeanFactory when getObject() is called ?
Specifically in this case I'm not interested in SpringConfig (no @Bean please)

The dependant class requests all of the FooBean(s) to be injected into it:

```
@Autowired(required = true)
private FooBean[] foobeans;
```

Answer (score 0):

`FactoryBean` has a method `isSingleton()` - it should return `false` if you want the factory to produce more than one bean. Check its javadocs for more details (it mentions `SmartFactoryBean`)

Comment: Could you please elaborate? What should I return from getObject() ? Would it be called repeatedly like an iterator ?

Comment: it would be called each time a bean instance is requested.

Comment: I've added to the question the dependant class field which requires all FooBean(s). How would spring know how many times should it call FooBeanFactory#getObject() ?

Comment: I guess it won't call it at all - it will just look for existing ones and not find any. If you want a specific number, just declare N <bean> elements, all with the same factory bean, but different IDs